# Intro to Python HW assignment - need guidance

Tags: python, list, loops

I have to arrange this code(below) in the right order to iterate through list1 and get the proper sum of 10. It's also missing a line of code(i think something to do with the .append method?) Any and all help is greatly appreciated!!

```
list1 = [1, [2, 3], 4]
stack = list1.copy()
item = stack.pop(0)
result = 0

while stack:
    for e in item:
    if type(item) is list:
    
    else:
        result += item

print(result)
```

Answer (score 0):

Your code is stuck in a dead loop because you haven't changed the value of stack, see the following code example.

1. if your list1 has a fixed structure, like the one in the question, there is only one layer of nesting, you can directly use the loop to solve the problem：

```
list1 = [1, [2, 3], 4]
stack = []
result = 0

for item in list1:
    if isinstance(item, int):
        stack.append(item)
        result += item
    else:
        for num in item:
            stack.append(num)
            result += num

print(stack, result)
```

2. if your list1 list has multiple layers of nested lists, we suggest using recursive ideas to split the list first:

```
def solution(lst):
    res = []
    for item in lst:
        if type(item) is list:
            res.extend(solution(item))
        else:
            res.append(item)
    return res

list1 = [1, [2, 3], 4]
stack2 = solution(list1)
print(stack2, sum(stack2))
```

Comment: thank you for the response! this has definitely helped my understanding a bit, but for the assignment i HAVE to use the lines of code i posted. the only thing i can add is one line of code using the .append method. i know the code is in the wrong order, but i cant figure out where im going wrong.